# Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Pumpmate Fuel Management\PB.MDB' because it does not exist

Tags: copy-item

I'm trying to run a powershell command where it makes a copy of the file "PB.mdb" in a specific location, renames it with a timestamp at the end of it, and saves it in a different location.

Here is my code:

```
$sourcePath = "C:\Pumpmate Fuel Management\PB.MDB"
$destinationPath = "C:Temp\TEST\PM - Backups\"
$timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
Copy-Item $sourcePath $destinationPath
Rename-Item "$destinationPath\PB.MDB" "PB_$timestamp.MDB"
```

When I run it, I get this outcome:
Copy-Item: Cannot find path C:Pumpmate Fuel ManagementPB.MDB because it does not exist.

Please assist.

Kind Regards,
Gaston

Comment: Powershell does not have the habit of lying ... Are you sure that file exists at that specific location? Typos in the filename? Is the error message really without the backslashes?

Comment: Yes I'e confirmed C:\Pumpmate Fuel Management\PB.MDB is the correct path.

Comment: This is the error I'll get:
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Pumpmate Fuel Management\PB.MDB' because it does not exist.
At C:\Temp\PM test.ps1:4 char:1
Copy-Item $sourcePath $destinationPath
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Pumpmate Fuel Management\PB.MDB:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: Then this file does not exist. Open the windows explorer in that directory, right click on that file and then do "copy as path". Put that copied path in your script ... Maybe your path contains a hidden space or some special character ...